# Code Explanation - Please

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Sorry - I hope you don't mind me asking this question but I am new to SQL - Could someone comments on what these lines mean in this code:

```
select b.recipeuuid
      ,b.proditemuuid
      ,b.proditemvalueuuid
  into #rectemp
  from rec_recipe as a
       inner join rec_recipevalue as b
               on b.recipeuuid=a.recipeuuid
              and b.[value] in ('Green','Yellow')
       inner join rec_proditem as c
               on c.proditemuuid=b.proditemuuid
       inner join rec_proditemvalue as d
               on d.proditemuuid=c.proditemuuid
              and d.proditemvalueuuid=b.proditemvalueuuid
              and d.[name]='SetupType'
;

update a
   set a.[value]='1'
  from rec_recipevalue as a
       inner join #rectemp as b
               on b.recipeuuid=a.recipeuuid
              and b.proditemuuid=a.proditemuuid
              and b.proditemvalueuuid=a.proditemvalueuuid
 where a.[value] in ('Green','Yellow')
;

update a
   set a.[name]='Normal'
  from rec_proditemvalue as a
       inner join #rectemp as b
               on b.proditemuuid=a.proditemuuid
              and b.proditemvalueuuid=a.proditemvalueuuid
 where a.[name]='SetupType'
;

drop table #rectemp;
```

I understand that the general idea of this code. It is about how to update (or change) the value for two different columns: Attribute & Color. These two items are located in two different tables before I joined them with the appropriate UUID.
The update should take a place only when the Attribute = ‘SetupType’ and the Color = ‘Green’ or ‘Yellow’

I would like to change these two values to:

Attribute = ‘Normal’ and the
Color = ‘1’

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.recipeuuid
      ,b.proditemuuid
      ,b.proditemvalueuuid
  into #rectemp
  from rec_recipe as a
       inner join rec_recipevalue as b
               on b.recipeuuid=a.recipeuuid
              and b.[value] in ('Green','Yellow')
       inner join rec_proditem as c
               on c.proditemuuid=b.proditemuuid
       inner join rec_proditemvalue as d
               on d.proditemuuid=c.proditemuuid
              and d.proditemvalueuuid=b.proditemvalueuuid
              and d.[name]='SetupType'
;
***#rectemp is a temp table. Data imported into the table***
update a
   set a.[value]='1'
  from rec_recipevalue as a
       inner join #rectemp as b
               on b.recipeuuid=a.recipeuuid
              and b.proditemuuid=a.proditemuuid
              and b.proditemvalueuuid=a.proditemvalueuuid
 where a.[value] in ('Green','Yellow')
;
  ***Column Value is updated to 1 based on Value is Green or yellow***
update a
   set a.[name]='Normal'
  from rec_proditemvalue as a
       inner join #rectemp as b
               on b.proditemuuid=a.proditemuuid
              and b.proditemvalueuuid=a.proditemvalueuuid
 where a.[name]='SetupType'
;
  *** Name column is updated to Normal ***
drop table #rectemp;
  *** Temp Table is dropped***
```

Comment: How about this:  select b.recipeuuid
       ,b.proditemuuid
       ,b.proditemvalueuuid
  into #rectemp
  from rec_recipe as a
       inner join rec_recipevalue as b
               on b.recipeuuid=a.recipeuuid
              and b.[value] in ('Green','Yellow')
       inner join rec_proditem as c
               on c.proditemuuid=b.proditemuuid
       inner join rec_proditemvalue as d
               on d.proditemuuid=c.proditemuuid
              and d.proditemvalueuuid=b.proditemvalueuuid
              and d.[name]='SetupType'